# Rabbi Yerucham Levovitz source of quote

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, mussar-ethics

> Woe to a man who is unaware of his faults, he is not attentive to what
> needs repair.
>
> But double woe to he who is unaware of his virtues, he is unskilled
> in the tools of the trade!”

Where is this quote of   Rabbi Yerucham Levovitz?
​

Comment: Hi and welcome to Mi Yodeya! It would be helpful if you could also write where you heard/read this.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Aish](https://www.aish.co.il/sp/pg/489165891.html), the quote comes from Rabbi Yerucham's Even Sapir, pg. 72:

> "אמר הגאון רבי ירוחם ממיר (בספר 'אבן ספיר' עמוד ע"ב): "אוי לו לאדם שאינו מכיר ליקויי נפשו, שהרי אינו יודע מה עליו לתקן... אבל, אוי ואבוי לו לאדם שאינו מכיר את מעלותיו - כי הן אפילו את כלי עבודתי אינו מכיר"."

[This site](http://dafyomireview.com/article.php?docid=99&style=print) says it comes from [Rabbi Wolbe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Wolbe)'s Alei Shur:

> "Rabbi Yerucham Levovitz zt'l said: "Oy (woe) to he who doesn't recognize his faults. But oy vavoy (double woe) to he who doesn't recognize his qualities because even the tools of his trade he doesn't have." (from Alei Shur)
>
> His talmid, Rabbi Shlomo Wolbe zt'l explained:
> Every person is given a special trait or quality that with this trait he can change and transform himself completely to the good - and this is all of a person's job in this world, because through this he will reach all of his perfection - and this also applies for the negative side (i.e. to turn away from one's special negative trait). (Alei Shur shaar 3 pg.146)

It's likely that Rabbi Wolbe, being a student of Rabbi Yerucham, heard it directly from him and not from his book.